# PHP chunked upload. How i know it's finished?

Tags: php, file-upload, blueimp

I use the jquery uploader, what was created by blueimp.
https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

In the source there is a PHP uploader. That's what i use my project. It's work perfectly, but i have to know when a chunked file upload is finished, becouse i want to move and rename that file.

There is the PHP:
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/tree/master/server/php

Is it any solution to know when a chunked file upload is finished? Is it send any data in the header?

Comment: Couldn't you customize the php and return your own success/error code? There's a way to see script responses in Chrome in the developers console > network tab.